# Clear select field options based on another field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

**Live Demo** https://jsfiddle.net/barrycorrigan/23hxgw6y/2/

So I have a form that has a few select fields that are hidden and only appear based on what you select from another field. Which is working with no problems.

My problem is when the form get submitted and the user has chosen a few different options from other fields (because they are only hidden). They still appear in the submitted form.

Is there a way to clear the options from the other fields if they are hidden?
Also I know this code is really dirty so if anyone has any tips on making it cleaner I would be grateful for the advice.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

toggleFields(); //call this first so we start out with the correct visibility depending on the selected form values
//this will call our toggleFields function every time the selection value of our underAge field changes

$("#form1_segment").change(function() {
  toggleFields();
});

//this toggles the visibility of our parent permission fields depending on the current selected value of the underAge field
function toggleFields() {
  if ($("#form1_segment").val() == 'Food Service') {
    $("#form1_product").show();

    $("#form1_product_bc").hide();
    $("#form1_product_in").hide();
    $("#form1_product_hc").hide();
    $("#form1_product_auto").hide();
    $("#form1_product_aero").hide();

  } else if ($("#form1_segment").val() == 'Building Care') {
    $("#form1_product_bc").show();

    $("#form1_product").hide();
    $("#form1_product_in").hide();
    $("#form1_product_hc").hide();
    $("#form1_product_auto").hide();
    $("#form1_product_aero").hide();

  } else if ($("#form1_segment").val() == 'Industry') {
    $("#form1_product_in").show();

    $("#form1_product").hide();
    $("#form1_product_bc").hide();
    $("#form1_product_hc").hide();
    $("#form1_product_auto").hide();
    $("#form1_product_aero").hide();

  } else if ($("#form1_segment").val() == 'Health Care') {
    $("#form1_product_hc").show();

    $("#form1_product").hide();
    $("#form1_product_bc").hide();
    $("#form1_product_in").hide();
    $("#form1_product_auto").hide();
    $("#form1_product_aero").hide();

  } else if ($("#form1_segment").val() == 'Automotive') {
    $("#form1_product_auto").show();

    $("#form1_product").hide();
    $("#form1_product_bc").hide();
    $("#form1_product_in").hide();
    $("#form1_product_hc").hide();
    $("#form1_product_aero").hide();

  } else if ($("#form1_segment").val() == 'Aerospace') {
    $("#form1_product_aero").show();

    $("#form1_product").hide();
    $("#form1_product_bc").hide();
    $("#form1_product_in").hide();
    $("#form1_product_hc").hide();
    $("#form1_product_auto").hide();

  } else {
    $("#form1_product").hide();
    $("#form1_product_bc").hide();
    $("#form1_product_in").hide();
    $("#form1_product_hc").hide();
    $("#form1_product_auto").hide();
    $("#form1_product_aero").hide();
  }
}
});
```

Comment: You can add a class to all your form parts like `.form-part` instead of hiding/showing every IDs and do `$('.form-part).hide()` followed by `$('#Id_i_want_to_show').show();`

Comment: Before sending the form you can also remove the useless elements from the DOM using `$('selector').remove()`

Comment: Whenever you receive data, you can always check what has been selected and based on it you can ignore rest values. for e.g `form1_segment` has `Industry` then take `form1_product_bc`, `form1_product_in` etc.

Comment: Your ifs can be improved by storing `$("#form1_segment").val()` in a variable and testing against this variable, you'll avoid calling `.val()` multiple times

Comment: Only use one `<select>` and set the options accordingly. Or disable all the other `<select>`

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle that uses a class name to hide/disable all and then shows and enables the one you should show. If the select is both hidden and disabled it should be ignored? https://jsfiddle.net/23hxgw6y/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `^` starts with selector to find all selects with `id` starting with `form1_product` to hide them all and clear their value. then `switch` to display the correct select.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  toggleFields();

  $("#form1_segment").change(function() {
    toggleFields();
  });

  function toggleFields() {

    $("[id^=form1_product]").hide().val(null);

    switch ($("#form1_segment").val()) {
      case "Food Service":
        $("#form1_product").show();
        break;
      case "Building Care":
        $("#form1_product_bc").show();
        break;
      case "Industry":
        $("#form1_product_in").show();
        break;
      case "Health Care":
        $("#form1_product_hc").show();
        break;
      case "Automotive":
        $("#form1_product_auto").show();
        break;
      case "Aerospace":
        $("#form1_product_aero").show();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1_contact" class="contact-form" action="/en-us/contact" method="post">
  <div>
    <input id="form1_name" name="name" class="contact-form__input" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" required="required" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="form1_email" name="email" class="contact-form__input" placeholder="Email address" type="email" required="required" />
  </div>
  <div class="split-form">
    <label for="form1_segment">Segment</label>
    <select id="form1_segment" name="segment" class="test">
      <option value="Select a Segment">Select a Segment</option>
      <option value="Food Service">Food Service</option>
      <option value="Building Care">Building Care</option>
      <option value="Industry">Industry</option>
      <option value="Health Care">Health Care</option>
      <option value="Automotive">Automotive</option>
      <option value="Aerospace">Aerospace</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="split-form last">
    <label for="form1_product">Product</label>
    <select id="form1_product" name="product" class="test">
      <option value="Select a product">Select a product</option>
      <option value="S.U.D.S.® Single Use Dispensing System">S.U.D.S.® Single Use Dispensing System</option>
      <option value="Chix® SC Foodservice Towels">Chix® SC Foodservice Towels</option>
      <option value="Chix® SC Foodservice Towels">Chix® SC Foodservice Towels</option>
      <option value="Chix® Pro-Quat®">Chix® Pro-Quat®</option>
      <option value="Chix® Pro-Quat®">Chix® Pro-Quat®</option>
      <option value="Chix® Pro-Quat®">Chix® Pro-Quat®</option>
      <option value="Chix® Pro-Chlor®">Chix® Pro-Chlor®</option>
      <option value="Chix® Microfiber Light Cloths">Chix® Microfiber Light Cloths</option>
      <option value="Chix® Plus with Microban">Chix® Plus with Microban</option>
      <option value="Chix® Towels with Microban">Chix® Towels with Microban</option>
      <option value="Chix® Towels">Chix® Towels</option>
      <option value="Chix® Plus Sanitizing">Chix® Plus Sanitizing</option>
      <option value="Chix® Soft Cloth">Chix® Soft Cloth</option>
      <option value="Chix® Tough">Chix® Tough</option>
      <option value="Chix® All Day™">Chix® All Day™</option>
      <option value="Chix® Wet Wipes">Chix® Wet Wipes</option>
      <option value="Chix® Competitive Wet Wipes">Chix® Competitive Wet Wipes</option>
      <option value="Chix® Economy Towels">Chix® Economy Towels</option>
      <option value="Chix® 3000">Chix® 3000</option>
      <option value="Quix® Pretreated Towels">Quix® Pretreated Towels</option>
      <option value="Chix® Apron">Chix® Apron</option>
      <option value="Worxwell®">Worxwell®</option>
    </select>
    <select id="form1_product_bc" name="product_bc" class="test">
      <option value="Select a product">Select a product</option>
      <option value="Dusty™ High Performance Dust Cloth">Dusty™ High Performance Dust Cloth</option>
      <option value="Masslinn® Heavy Duty Dust Cloth">Masslinn® Heavy Duty Dust Cloth</option>
      <option value="S.U.D.S.® Single Use Dispensing System">S.U.D.S.® Single Use Dispensing System</option>
      <option value="Masslinn® Medium Duty Dust Cloth">Masslinn® Medium Duty Dust Cloth</option>
      <option value="Masslinn® Light Duty Dust Cloth">Masslinn® Light Duty Dust Cloth</option>
      <option value="Economy Duster">Economy Duster</option>
      <option value="Masslinn Dusting Tools">Masslinn Dusting Tools</option>
    </select>
    <select id="form1_product_in" name="product_in" class="test">
      <option value="Select a product">Select a product</option>
      <option value="Durawipe® Heavy Duty Shop Towel">Durawipe® Heavy Duty Shop Towel</option>
    </select>
    <select id="form1_product_hc" name="product_hc" class="test">
      <option value="Select a product">Select a product</option>
      <option value="Worxwell® Towels">Worxwell® Towels</option>
      <option value="Soft Cloth Patient Wipes">Soft Cloth Patient Wipes</option>
      <option value="Professional Series">Professional Series</option>
      <option value="Dwell™ Disinfectant Compatible Healthcare Towels">Dwell™ Disinfectant Compatible Healthcare Towels</option>
      <option value="Dusty™ High Performance Dust Cloths">Dusty™ High Performance Dust Cloths</option>
    </select>
    <select id="form1_product_auto" name="product_auto" class="test">
      <option value="No products available">No products available</option>
    </select>
    <select id="form1_product_aero" name="product_aero" class="test">
      <option value="No products available">No products available</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea id="form1_message" name="message" class="contact-form__input  contact-form__textarea" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="form1_submit" name="submit" class="btn  btn__round  subform__button" value="Send Message" type="submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```